# LInkify block onclick event

Tags: android, onclick, textview, linkify

I have some TextView objects that I have onclick listeners assigned to. The onclick listeners work fine unless I run Linkify.addLinks on the TextView objects, at which point the onclick event never happens. This happens regardless of whether anything in the TextView is actually linkified. Is there a way to have both events happen, or at least be able to predict whether anything is or would be linkified in the text?

Comment: At this point I'm not sure there is an answer to this. I will continue to vote up any answers anyone provides here, though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle clicks on TextView's links while using Linkify for finding and setting the links inside the text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242000/handle-clicks-on-textviews-links-while-using-linkify-for-finding-and-setting-th)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found an answer or not as this question is rather old, but I just found it while looking for another problem (not exactly similar) and I can help (a bit): there is an easy way to "detect" whether Linkify modifies the text: just compares it with the original. Something like:

```
String originalText = textView.getText().toString();
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
String linkifiedText = textView.getText().toString();

if (originalText.equals(linkifiedText)) {
    // linkify did not do anything...
}
```

Comment: Man you rock for responding to this old post. I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

`Linkify.addLinks()` returns a boolean which indicates if it found links in the text or not. There is no need to do a before/after comparison like Guillaume suggested.